# SwingWorker threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm working with swing at the minute and I've run into a bit of a problem,
I realize that it's not possible to execute a SwingWorker thread more than once
from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html.

My question is that is it possible to create a new instance of the same SwingWorker thread?
In the code here I've called the worker thread 'worker'

```
SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>(){
  public void doInBackGround(){

  }
};
```

Is it possible to create more than one instance of this thread so I can call it more than once? I've tried something like

```
(new SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker).execute();
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreicated!

Comment: `but this doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreicated!` for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, before that to check in  [Oracle tutorial whats  <Void, Void>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), my view no idea and bothering with how to simulating your un_know issue,

Comment: Switch from an anonymous class to a real class and create multiple instances ?

Comment: you mean create a class that extends SwingWorker? Would i still be able to call .execute() on an instance of this new class?

Comment: @Shanee Of course you would

Answer (score 2):

What is the problem about creating a new SwingWorker every time you need it?

If you need to store some state in the instance that needs to be run many times then you can use Runnable or Callable interfaces and give that to SwingWorker for execution. You have to create the SwingWorker every time, but the Runnable or Callable instance can be the same.

In the example below the worker instance is created every time but Runnable instances are always the same.

```
class Foo {
  private final Runnable executeInBackground;
  private final Runnable executeInDone;

  public Foo(Runnable done, Runnable background) {
     executeInDone = done;
     executeInBackground = background;
  }

  public void execute() {
     SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
        public void doInBackground() {
           executeInBackground.run();
        }

        public void done() {
           executeInDone.run();
        }
     };
     worker.execute();
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand you fully, any time i try to use the code above I get the error 'Cannot instantiate the type SwingWorker<Void,Void>' how do I 'use Runnable or Callable interfaces and give that to SwingWorker for execution'

Comment: SwingWorker isn't designated for this job, is created to redirect hard and long running task to WorkersThread, once time, not as reusable Object, use Executor for paraller or concurrently run, notice both Executor and SwingWorker aren't goog designed APIs, there are miss a bunch important notifiers in compare with standard Worker Threads based on Runnable.Thread or plain vanilla Thread

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try it the way it's done in the code above!

Comment: @oikku You may want to add `.execute()` at the end of the `SwingWorker`.